# Использование PDO в классах, написанных собственноручно

Tags: php, классы, pdo

вот почему в моем класса не определяется PDO, как мне реализовать использование PDO?

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: 5 звезд
 * Date: 12.12.2018
 * Time: 13:18
 */

namespace Sers;


class Sers
{
    public $dbs;

    function __construct($user, $pass, $host, $db){
        $opt = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_BOTH,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
        $this->dbs = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $user, $pass, $opt);
    }
    public function get_typ(){
        $r=$this->dbs->prepare("select * from typs;");
        $r->execute();
        return json_decode($r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Нашел ошибку, нужно после namespace Sers; написать use PDO;

Comment: Или `new \PDO(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так использовать PDO в собственноручно написанных классах **нельзя**.

Это приведет к [открытию стольких соединений с БД](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#connection), сколько объектов будет создано в программе. А это могут быть сотни и тысячи.

В собственноручно написанные классы ПДО надо передавать как параметр конструктора.

Кроме того, в коде есть две ошибки

- во-первых, код работы с данными не должен заниматься их форматированием. Он должен только возвращать данные, а форматированием должно выполняться при выводе.
- во-вторых, `json_decode($r);` в принципе не делает ничего полезного.

Поэтому код должен быть таким.

```
class Sers
{
    protected $dbs;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo) {
        $this->dbs = $pdo;
    }
    public function get_typ(){
        $stmt = $this->dbs->query("select * from typs");
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

И вызываться как-то так

```
require_once 'pdo.php';
$sers = new Sers ($pdo);
echo json_encode($sers->get_typ());
```

Comment: Поменяйте, пожалуйста "Так использовать" на "Таким образом использовать", потому что иначе можно воспринять это как посыл не использовать PDO в собственноручно написанных классах вообще. К тому же, непонятно, почему Вы советуете передавать PDO параметром, в то время как при использовании одной БД (а это, как я понимаю, наиболее распространённый случай) удобнее вообще использовать синглтон-реализацию обёртки для PDO.